# How close validation CSRF token in form?

Tags: php, symfony

I have created API and send data through API but form check CSRF validation throws error message. So i don't need this CSRF validation in particular form. I don't want to check CSRF  validation token for this particular form.

please help me to do this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you be a little more specific please. Like a bit of code!

Comment: Like I have create api and send data through api but form check CSRF validation and give me error message. So i don't need this CSRF validation in particular form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{   
 $resolver->setDefaults(array('csrf_protection' => false))
}
```

Comment: @AshokChitroda Please note that this will disable CSRF protection on everything... even authentication.

Comment: And where do you guy put this? Please be more explicit

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice [article](https://medium.com/@barryvdh/csrf-protection-in-laravel-explained-146d89ff1357#.1yugwhntu) explaining the threats of not using CSRF. Please look at your code again, and go over the sections that is causing you to create forms without CSRF, and see if you can re-think the logic.

Add this input field to your form to include the CSRF token.

`<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

But if you have your mind set on disabling CSRF (which I highly recommend against), you can extend the VerifyCsrfToken array with NO CSRF URLs as explained in this [laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-disable-csrf-middleware-on-certain-routes).

Comment: I send data through api so not pass CSRF token

Comment: if you include `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">` in your form, and send the form data through ajax, the csrf token will be sent with the request. That way you don't have to disable csrf.

Comment: @AshokChitroda You can also set the csrf for ajax in the headers like this: `$.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'csrftoken' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' } });`

Comment: The user isn't using a form on a web page, he is using a form class to handle a submission via an API. To quote a Laracast answer "An API is not something you want to use CSRF for... API's are meant for Cross Site Requests".